# Перевод шестнадцатеричной строки в изображение

Tags: python

Google-таблица по адресу https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UAxqf6Ml1AHfOvpvPVEakpZeaonOdM0SP4NJjOPPfkw/edit?usp=drive_open&ouid=107698653281780380405 хранит в себе последовательность байт в виде разбитой на ячейки зашифрованной шестнадцатеричной строки, по две цифры в строке на байт. Шифр основан на сдвиге, таком, что цифрам 0..F соответствуют символы ‘a’..‘p’ (первые шестнадцать букв латинского алфавита). Эта шестнадцатеричная строка представляет собой двоичный файл, внутри которого хранится изображение в некотором известном формате. Как получить данный файл?

Я все ячейки таблиц склеил в одну строку и перевёл в нормальный шестнадцатеричный формат (возможно я где-то ошибаюсь):

```
t='pndhhkfifkaaaaaeog.. и тд'
d={
    'a':'0',
    'b':'1',
    'c':'2',
    'd':'3',
    'e':'4',
    'f':'5',
    'g':'6',
    'h':'7',
    'i':'8',
    'j':'9',
    'k':'a',
    'l':'b',
    'm':'c',
    'n':'d',
    'o':'e',
    'p':'f',
}
s=''
for i in tmp:
    s+=d[i]
```

Подскажите как действовать дальше, и вообще, в ту сторону я иду?

Answer (score 1):

Как-то маловато информации о конечном результате, но принципиально схема должна быть какой-то такой (имена переменных оставил ваши):

```
s = ''.join([d[x] for x in t]) # получаем расшифрованную строку в соотв. со словарем
s = bytes.fromhex(s)           # переводим ее в шестнадцатиричный формат

with open('image.ext', 'wb') as f:  # и бинарно записываем это все в файл.
    f.write(s)
```

Ваш файл, кстати, имеет в начале сигнатуру 7z archive.